# Is a hashgacha required for freshly squeezed orange juice?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Does freshly squeezed orange juice require a hashgacha? (ex: the freshly squeezed orange juice at Whole Foods)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Aryeh and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: are they squeezing it on the spot for you, or is it sold in bottles?

Comment: If you're talking about getting freshly squeezed OJ from a juice cart or store that squeezes the oranges in one of those automated machines, I can't envision a problem. The only items I've seen going into these machines are citrus fruits. I can't fathom grapes fitting into this machine, anyway, and even if it were, it **might** be nullified in 1/60 anyway. Whole oranges are stacked into the top of the machine and the machine cuts and squeezes fruits. As for a manual process, here too, usually the knife used is for just the fruits, and there's no problem cutting grape stems (cont.)

Comment: The only problem here might be if they use the same machine to make grape juice.

Comment: Another problem might be orlah and/ or ma’aser, if you’re in Israel (and orlah even outside of israel, if you know the fruit tree belongs to a Jew).

Answer (score 3):

From the **cRc** [juice list](http://www.crcweb.org/juice_list.php):

> Fresh (refrigerated) orange juice should preferably be purchased with reliable kosher certification.  If that is not available or there is a particular brand that is considerably lower in price, **one may purchase orange juice that is not certified, as long as it does not contain any kosher-sensitive ingredients** (e.g. colors, flavors, other juices).

**practicalhalacha.com** "[When Hechsher NOT Needed](http://www.practicalhalacha.com/halacha.php?id=2148)" writes:

> Pure fruit juice NOT made from concentrate (such as orange or pineapple juice) does not normally require a hechsher (except for grape juice, which always requires a hechsher!).

However, see **ShulchanAruchHaRav.com**'s "[Juice without a hashgacha](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/juice-without-hashgacha/)" for additional considerations.

As always, safest bet is to [CYLOR](https://www.yourdictionary.com/cylor).

Comment: +1 but you might want to add the case of a machine preparing fresh orange juice on premise, which I think is the case of the OP. Like made from real oranges with nothing else (yes it exists!)